# Read a file of mixed items and retain their data types

Tags: python

I have a TSV file that consists of integers along with some false data that could be anything such as floats or characters etc.

The idea is to read the contents of the file and find out which ones are bad (containing data other than integers)

Each line can be read using the readline method once the file has been opened for reading. Off course, the readline() method returns each line read as a string and not it's constituent data types. My understanding is, that I could use the `pickle` module somehow to ensure that i retain the original data type by representing it as it's serialized version carrying out dump and load methods.

The question is, how do I do this?

By reading each line and pickling it, would not help since readline by default reads it as a string. Thereby upon pickling, it's really just pickling a string into a serialized python object representation and unpickling would only return it as a string. Thus the actual data in the line, such as integers or chars are being represented as strings irrespective.

So I assume the question is, how do I pickle things the right way OR how do I process each line of a file ensuring that it's data types are being maintained?

Comment: If you were pickling your data then you wouldnt need newlines. Just pickle a list.

Comment: An example of what you are really trying to accomplish would help muchly. As it is, it looks like you are asking how to tell whether a field is an integer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if you are getting the string from pickle,just split the string using '\t' then use

```
a = "0343523"
a.isdigit()
True

b = "934sjsspam"
b.isdigit()
False
```

There is one more method for unicodes also [unicodes numeric check](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isnumeric) , so just use them

and maintain the data types

Comment: Yes, and if your data is obtained by `readline()`, then `pickle` has nothing to do with your problem and cannot contribute to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

To start, addressing the use of pickling, you would not go about it by pickling each line individually to a file. The ascii format uses newlines as it is, and it would just make a messy file. By simply pickling your entire data as a data structure, you could retain information about the whole thing...Example:

```
from cPickle import loads, dumps
from types import IntType

line1 = [1, 2, 3]
line2 = [1.0, 'foo', 'bar']
line3 = [4, 5, 6]
pickled = dumps((line1, line2, line3))
# ((lp1\nI1\naI2\naI3\na(lp2\nF1\naS'foo'\np3\naS'bar'\np4\na(lp5\nI4\naI5\naI6\nat.
unpickled = loads(pickled)
# ([1, 2, 3], [1.0, 'foo', 'bar'], [4, 5, 6])

print all(isinstance(i, IntType) for i in line1)
# True
print all(isinstance(i, IntType) for i in line2)
# False
```

The objects are clearly typed now when you bring them back in.

Now pickling aside, if you cant controll the format of the source file, you can simply test each tab-separated line:

```
line1 = '1\t2\t3'
line2 = '1.0\tfoo\tbar'
line3 = '4\t5\t6'

print all(map(str.isdigit, line1.split('\t')))
# True
print all(map(str.isdigit, line2.split('\t')))
# False
print all(map(str.isdigit, line3.split('\t')))
# True
```

Comment: thanks for this, I am trying to understand one of your statements better and wrap my head around it better... if you can elaborate?..."By simply pickling your entire data as a data structure", the data in this case is being read from a fileObject... each line is technically read in as a string say line1 has been read in..can you expand your answer to accomodate a file in this context?

Comment: That comments was in respect to you saying you wanted it to retain the python object types. That can only be possible if you create the file completely in the first place by pickling out all the data as a big structure like a list of lists. If the file is already a plain text TSV then you have to just parse it like my other example

Answer (score 0):

The TSV file has already lost all the type information.

If the pickle module had been used to write out the file, you would have been able to easily unpickle it, however it looks like you just get to read the damaged file, so pickle is no use to you here

The best you can do is attempt to convert each field to `int` and handle the exception if it fails

Comment: the pickle module is not being used to write to the file, the intention is to read the file and ensure it's data integrity using the pickle module and not simply reading the file

Comment: @user1020069, You are hoping for some magic. The pickle module is not magic. If you use `pickle` to write the file you can use `unpickle` to read it. Any other file won't work with `unpickle`

Comment: I am trying to pickle in the data from the file ...that is read it not write to it

Comment: @user1020069: you dont pickle in a file. You pickle a file out and unpickle it back in as objects. You cant unpickle what was not first pickled.